# Emulator for Deploying and Debugging

Tags: dot42

Do you provide any emulator with dot42 or an actual device is required for testing/debugging?

Is there any way some third party emulator can be attached to debug applications?

Answer (score 0):

You require either an actual device or you can use a VM: http://blog.dot42.com/2013/08/running-android-43-in-hyper-v.html